# HF flux core welder power requirements?

Tags: electrical, welding

**Item/product:** Harbor Freight Titanium Easy-Flux125 welder.

**Question:** Which piece of information to use?

**Source:** Operators manual for specific device.

**References:** Images copied directly from manual, pages 7 and 10 respectively.

[image: current input specification]

[image: step 14 instructions]

As show above, the device appears to draw 23.5 amperes current. The instructions (2nd panel) indicate that it is to be connected to a 20 ampere capacity outlet. While the installed plug is not a strictly 20 ampere plug, one can make allowances in this case.

My understanding of outlets, power and general electrical applications is that one should use wiring and outlets rated to 80% of required power. This means that the outlet should be about 30 amp capable, along with matching wiring.

Should one presume that the listed current input is expected to be a maximum value? Is this concept supported by the reference to the entry stating to use a delayed-action breaker? Related to this, can one expect to periodically pop the breaker?

As requested in the comments, here's the info plate on the side of the machine:

[image: welder info plate]

Comment: With just the power and current inputs you would be right, but manufacturer instructions are what you go by if provided.  This is assuming the unit is UL listed.

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the unit's nameplate please?

Comment: I don't own it but the friend will be visiting Monday and I'll snap a photo and add it.

Comment: @crip659 HF sells these units in their B&M stores here in the US. While they're all made in China, I'd strongly suspect that they are, at least, UL listed. (And some of their welders are actually pretty highly rated, even in comparison to the big name brands.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info plate presenting I1eff = 12.6A and research showing the following:

> According to the informational note in 630.12(B), "I1eff is the
> maximum value of the effective supply currrent".

one might consider that the 20A outlet requirement fits into the 80% rule and that there should be minimal concern for overloading the circuit.

The welder was used today within the 30% rate duty cycle and experienced no overheating, no circuit breaker tripping, and no other power related complications.